# PHP website getting hacked - dir names changed

Tags: apache-http-server, php, malware, cgi

I'm new to PHP and Apache. I come from Node.js/Java backends and I'm new to this tech stack (PHP, CGI, Apache etc). My site currently uses ckeditor to handle user uploads and has high traffic. Often, someone, somehow just changes the names of my directories. So my `views` dir is suddenly `views1` and now my entire site stops working. I have 775 permission on my files but that shouldn't allow random requests to simply write to my dirs as far as I know.

How can I prevent this? I know it is hard to diagnose with so few information, but I'm not really sure how to tackle the situation.

I don't allow any kind of shady files to be uploaded through `.htaccess`

```
<FilesMatch "\.(inc|tpl|h|ihtml|ini|conf|class|bin|spd|theme|module|sql)$">
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

What are the ways that someone can change the name of my directories so easily?

Comment: 775 mode doesn't tell us the whole thing. It indicates a process of the same group can modify your directory. Then the group of the directory and the group of the Apache server is needed to figure out if their is a vulnerability. On the site I have, the 775 right is only put on directory where I expect Apache/PHP needs to right something, for example a joint file.

Comment: I'm not using Node.js at all. I just said I come from a Node.js/Java backend env and now I'm working with PHP, CGI and Apache as the backend of my service.

Comment: OK, corrected. You should also give more information (are there custom made PHP files, a common PHP site like Wordpress, vBulletin, phpBB... which version...)

Comment: Well, pretty much all my php files are custom made. I don't use Wordpress or anything like that. I'm using PHP CGI 7.4.33

Comment: You should perhaps restrict the moed of directories which shouldn't change to 755. Note, a attacker which manage to change directory names can install a Webshell and ease its future access. You should verify that all PHP files are yours.

Comment: It's unlikely that PHP was hacked, or your computer would have been infected. I suggest to search for "views" in all your PHP files to try and locate the code that does it. If you can't find it, add trace inside the code to better locate where it's happening.

Comment: So you're saying that the attacker probably managed to sneak in a .php file to run a script that changed my dir name?

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer omg I found it. There really was a .php file that was not mine changing the dir names. I removed it but as you guys said its already probably infected now.

Comment: Check webserver logs. You have to patch the vulnerability that was used to upload that file.

Comment: Yep. Just found it all out. You guys are awesome. Wish I could upvote all of you. Thank you so much

Comment: Its worth pointing out that FilesMatch does not prevent anything being uploaded - and its almost impossible to use htaccess to prevent uploads using .htaccess.  To prevent thus happening again you either need to work out what php was being abused to allow the file to be created (ie fix your input sanitization) or prevent the user the website is running at from running files - ideally bith (vut the latter may not be practical)